# How to make multiple divs display in one line but still retain width?

Tags: css

Normally, you set elements to display: inline if you want them to display in the same line. However setting an element to inline means that the width attribute would be meaningless.

How do you make divs to be in the same line without making them inline?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block`.

This property allows a DOM element to have all the attributes of a block element, but keeping it inline. There's some drawbacks, but most of the time it's good enough. [Why it's good and why it may not work for you.](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)

**EDIT:** The only *modern* browser that has some problems with it is IE7. See [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Comment: You can also float them, but that comes with its own set of caveats.

Comment: can elaborate on quirks in other browsers? I am interested. question +1

Comment: @cctan You can read more [here](http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html). Basically, the problem is that IE7 and IE6 only apply `inline-block` to elements that are displayed inline. It can be fixed though as explained on that website.

Comment: @lomegor i see, thats unfortunate for IE7 & IE6. I will keep that info in mind. comment +1

Comment: Doesn't `inline-block` add default whitespace that throws off content and is difficult to make up for?

Comment: @Eric more precisely, white-space in your HTML code will affect the rendering. If you don't want extra space added, don't put any space between elements, that is, keep them all stuck together on the same line of HTML code.

Comment: I had to use `white-space: nowrap` too. Parent div is of fixed width for me and in that 5 child divs have to show in one line even if they overflow on the right side.

Answer (score 21):

I used the property

```
display: table;
```

and

```
display: table-cell;
```

to achieve the same.Link to fiddle below shows 3 tables wrapped in divs and these divs are further wrapped in a parent div

```
<div id='content'>
   <div id='div-1'><!-- Contains table --></div>
   <div id='div-2'><!-- contains two more divs that require to be arranged one below other --></div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vikikamath/QU6WP/1/
I thought this might be helpful to someone looking to set divs in same line without using display-inline.

Comment: +1 This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I set the two divs that I wanted to be displayed side by side to `display:table-cell` and it works perfect. So much better than float because it doesn't mess with any wrapping containers and you don't have to `clear:;` anything else. Thanks!!

Comment: I would prefer to use this approach than the other!! Thanks.

Comment: If you have a problem, the fix it with display:table, you then have 2 problems :/

Answer (score 10):

Flex is the better way. Just try..

```
display: flex;
```

Comment: Maybe add a short description as to what flex does?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `float:left` in DIV or use `<span>` tag, like

```
<div style="width:100px;float:left"> First </div> 
<div> Second </div> 
<br/>
```

or

```
<span style="width:100px;"> First </span> 
<span> Second </span> 
<br/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can float your column divs using float: left; and give them widths.

And to make sure none of your other content gets messed up, you can wrap the floated divs within a parent div and give it some clear float styling.

Hope this helps.