# CSS: Getting 2 children DIVs on same line

Tags: css, wordpress, html

Am using Ninja Forms on a WP website. There are 2 different fields (textbox & submit button) that are separate DIVs, both children of single DIV.

They appear on consecutive lines and I cannot seem to get the on same line. Help?

Can see current code of the DIVs on the site: http://theroadmap.co/generation/

```
<div id="ninja_forms_form_2_all_fields_wrap" class="ninja-forms-all-fields-wrap">
<div class="field-wrap text-wrap label-above ninjacomment-wrap" id="ninja_forms_field_9_div_wrap" data-visible="1">
<input type="hidden" id="ninja_forms_field_9_type" value="text">
<label for="ninja_forms_field_9" id="ninja_forms_field_9_label" class=""> </label>
<input id="ninja_forms_field_9" data-mask="" name="ninja_forms_field_9" type="text" class="ninja-forms-field ninjacomment " value="" rel="9">
<div id="ninja_forms_field_9_error" style="display:none;" class="ninja-forms-field-error">
</div>
</div>
<div class="field-wrap submit-wrap label-left ninjasubmit-wrap" id="ninja_forms_field_10_div_wrap" data-visible="1">
<input type="hidden" id="ninja_forms_field_10_type" value="submit">
<input type="submit" name="_ninja_forms_field_10" class="ninja-forms-field ninjasubmit" id="ninja_forms_field_10" value="Suggest a link!" rel="10">
<div id="ninja_forms_field_10_error" style="display:none;" class="ninja-forms-field-error">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Modifications I've added so far:

```
/* Ninja Form mods */
.ninjacomment {
background: #ffbf00 !important;
border: 3px;
color: black !important;
width: 50%;
}

#ninja_forms_field_9 {
margin-left: 0;
width: 30%;
float: left;
position: inline-block;
}


#ninja_forms_field_10 {
margin-left: 0;
float: right;
position: inline-block;
}

.ninja-forms-all-fields-wrap {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be best to recreate this using the minimal html/css necessary on something like http://jsbin.com

Comment: `.nav-links a { width:50%; display:inline-block; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make multiple divs display in one line but still retain width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920247/how-to-make-multiple-divs-display-in-one-line-but-still-retain-width) and many others

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get elements on the same line several ways.

Sample markup:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

#### inline-block

```
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%; /* adjust */
}
```

#### Floats

```
.child {
  float: left; /* or right */
  width: 40%; /*adjust */
}
```

#### display: table

```
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.child {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 40%; /* adjust */
}
```

#### white-space: nowrap

```
.parent {
  white-space: nowrap /* children will stay on the same line no matter how wide */
}
```

Comment: thank you! I managed to figure out using both this and the below information. Cheers!

Comment: this post is not at all specific to ninja forms so should be taken with a pinch of salt.  Even if it helped the question creator its a bad answer in itself

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
        <input id="ninja_forms_field_9" data-mask="" name="ninja_forms_field_9" type="text" class="ninja-forms-field ninjacomment " value="" rel="9"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <input type="submit" name="_ninja_forms_field_10" class="ninja-forms-field ninjasubmit" id="ninja_forms_field_10" value="Suggest a link!" rel="10"></input>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width:300px;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width:146px;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    width:148px;
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C9W3j/8/)