# PHP loop over HTML to create columns

Tags: php, html, grid, multiple-columns

I'm trying to build a horizontal sequence of product cards. So I'm using this:

```
<div class="row">
<?php
    $col = 3;
    $sql = "select distinct prd_prt_num, prd_cod, prd_dsc, prd_qtd_ven, fab_ape,";
    $sql .= " prf_ult_prc, prf_vis valor";
    $sql .= ", '' mensagem";
    $sql .= " from produtos";
    $sql .= " inner join fabricantes on (fab_cod=prd_fab_cod)";
    $sql .= " inner join produtos_fatores on (prf_prd_cod=prd_cod)";
    $sql .= " where prd_qtd_ven > 0";
    $sql .= " order by rand()"; 
    $sql .= " limit 4";

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql ."<p>". mysql_error());
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        extract($r,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,"c");

        if ($cor == "#ffffcc") {
            $cor = "#ffffff";
        } else {
            $cor = "#ffffcc";
        }

?>
<div class="content">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col s3">
         <div class="card">
      <img src="imagem.php?tam=195&src=<? echo $c_prd_prt_num; ?>" alt="<? echo $c_prd_prt_num; ?>">
      <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
        <h6><? echo $c_prd_dsc; ?></h6>
            <? if ($logado==1) { ?>
                <p><big><? echo $_SESSION['moeda']; ?> <? echo $c_valor; ?></big></p>
                <p><a href="produto.php?prd=<? echo $c_prd_cod; ?>" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="material-icons left">cart</i>COMPRAR</a></p>
            <? } else { ?>
                <p><a href="cadastro.php?prd=<? echo $c_prd_cod; ?>" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="material-icons left">shopping_cart</i>COMPRAR</a></p>
                <p><a href="produto.php?prd=<? echo $c_prd_cod; ?>" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="material-icons left">search</i>DETALHES</a></p>
            <? } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I'm using materialize framework and the "content" class is this:

```
  div.content { 
    width:1024px;
    margin:0 auto;
```

But I'm getting this:

[image: Screenshot]

How do I add more 3 columns?

Comment: Are you looping over the entire `html` code after your `while` loop that is what is causing issue ? Please correct your code.

Comment: Of interest with regards to [displaying divs on the same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920247/how-to-make-multiple-divs-display-in-one-line-but-still-retain-width)

Comment: Manijeta, sorry, but I'm new in html/css/php, so I don't get what I have to do.

Terminus, it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it. For who want to know what I did:

```
<div class="row">
<?php
    $col = 3;
    $sql = "select distinct prd_prt_num, prd_cod, prd_dsc, prd_qtd_ven, fab_ape,";
    $sql .= " prf_ult_prc, prf_vis valor";
    $sql .= ", '' mensagem";
    $sql .= " from produtos";
    $sql .= " inner join fabricantes on (fab_cod=prd_fab_cod)";
    $sql .= " inner join produtos_fatores on (prf_prd_cod=prd_cod)";
    $sql .= " where prd_qtd_ven > 0";
    $sql .= " order by rand()"; 
    //$sql .= " order by atualizacao desc";
    //$sql .= " limit $itenspagina";
    $sql .= " limit 4";







    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql ."<p>". mysql_error());
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        extract($r,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,"c");

        if ($cor == "#ffffcc") {
            $cor = "#ffffff";
        } else {
            $cor = "#ffffcc";
        }


?>
    <div class="col s3">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="imagem.php?tam=195&src=<? echo $c_prd_prt_num; ?>" alt="<? echo $c_prd_prt_num; ?>">
            <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                <h6><? echo $c_prd_dsc; ?></h6>
                <? if ($logado==1) { ?>
                    <p><big><? echo $_SESSION['moeda']; ?> <? echo $c_valor; ?></big></p>
                    <p><a href="produto.php?prd=<? echo $c_prd_cod; ?>" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="material-icons left">cart</i>COMPRAR</a></p>
                <? } else { ?>
                    <p><a href="cadastro.php?prd=<? echo $c_prd_cod; ?>" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="material-icons left">shopping_cart</i>COMPRAR</a></p>
                    <p><a href="produto.php?prd=<? echo $c_prd_cod; ?>" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="material-icons left">search</i>DETALHES</a></p>
                <? } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<? } ?>
</div>
```

Bye! Thanks