# Why don't the children of header container align horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have a main container called "header container" and two children containers called "logo-container" and "navigation-container". Here is the code:`

```css
.header-container {
}

.header-container figure nav{
    float: left;
}

.header-container .cisd-logo-container {
    margin-left: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px
}

.header-container img {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.navigation-container {
}`
```

```html
<header class="header-container">
  <figure class="logo-container">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo.png">
  </figure>

  <nav class="navigation-container">
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The two children containers don't align next to each other, Can anyone please explain why that is? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make multiple divs display in one line but still retain width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920247/how-to-make-multiple-divs-display-in-one-line-but-still-retain-width)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements - Figure is a "block" type element, not an "inline" type as the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0):

> The two children containers don't align next to each other, Can anyone
>   please explain why that is?

Because `div` element is a block-level element, it will occupy one line instead of sitting next to each other.

In order to make those containers align next to each other, try this:

```
    .navigation-container {
        float: left;
    }
    .logo-container{
        float: left;
    }
```

This is the demo:

```css
.header-container {
}

.header-container figure nav{
    float: left;
}

.header-container .cisd-logo-container {
    margin-left: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px
}

.header-container img {
    max-height: 100%;
}


.navigation-container {
    float: left;
}
.logo-container{
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-container">
    <figure class="logo-container">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo.png">
    </figure>

    <nav class="navigation-container">
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if Nguyễn Thanh Tú is correct, we are in 2018, so you should not use float property, because it will only make more troubles. Rather use flex.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Explanation in your case:

```
.header-container {
    display: flex; //align children next to each other
    align-items: center; // vertically align children to center
    justify-content: space-between; // horizontally align children to sides of container
}
```

```css
.header-container {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}

.header-container .cisd-logo-container {
    margin-left: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px
}

.header-container img {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.navigation-container {
}
```

```html
<header class="header-container">
  <figure class="logo-container">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo.png">
  </figure>

  <nav class="navigation-container">
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header-container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navigation-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navigation-container a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000000;
}
.navigation-container a:hover { 
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-container">
  <figure class="logo-container">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n80Drz/slash_logo.png" alt="logo.png">
  </figure>

  <nav class="navigation-container">
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: instead of using floats ,by using flex propeties                                               
       display: flex; 
    align-items: center; vertically align  to center
    justify-content: space-between; // horizontally align to center